# I have a requirement to restart my app after Every 3 hours

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

I'm developing android app in which I'm showing media in slide show. App remain working 24 by 7 as it is used for advertisement purpose but it automatically crashes sometimes after some days don't know why so client asked me to automatically restart the app after every 3 hours.
It should restart the complete app every time 3 hours spent

I have seen others answers on same question but they are not working for me

I'm calling this code in onCreate of my MainActivity

```
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,restatIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000,pendingIntent);
            System.exit(0);
```

this code close the app as soon as app opens and then start crashing the app with this error

**Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;**

I want to restart my app after every 3 hours periodically
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please attach full stack trace? Also, 1 suggestion You should show a dialog after three hours and exit the app on confirmation instead of exiting forcefully as it will lead to very bad user experience. Maybe user is reading something or watching something and the app exits randomly.

Comment: We have to do it forcefully its client requirement

Comment: Correct. I understood the requirement, but a dialog is also doing the same but it should be not dismissible `cancelable = false`. This will block the user from reading and inform them what happened instead of just closing it. Can you attach stacktrace?